# Angular application http.put is not sending input type="file" data to laravel Route::put, instead I am geting null data

Tags: laravel-8

Angular component.htm

```
        <div class="testForm">
            <form [formGroup]="newMemberForm" (ngSubmit)="onSave()">
              <!-- <div class="formGroup" formGroupName="memberDetail"> -->
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                  <mat-label> First Name</mat-label>
                  <input type="text" matInput formControlName="fname" />
                </mat-form-field>
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                  <mat-label> Last Name</mat-label>
                  <input type="text" matInput formControlName="lname" />
                </mat-form-field>
          
                <input
                  type="file"
                  (change)="newUploadFile($event)"
                  formControlName="image"
                />
          
                <img
                  *ngIf="displayedImageUrl"
                  [src]="displayedImageUrl"
                  alt="Member Image"
                  style="width: 100px"
                />
              <!-- </div> -->
              <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Save</button>
              <!-- <button type="button" (click)="updateMember()">Update</button> -->
            </form>
          </div>
```

My angular moudule.ts

```
        file_arr: any;
          newMembers: any[] = [];
          displayedImageUrl: any;
          isImageChanged = false; // Add this property to track if the image has been changed
          currentImageUrl: string | null = null; // To store the existing image URL
          constructor(
            private _fb: FormBuilder,
            private _memberService: MemberService,
            private _router: Router,
            private _activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,
            private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef
          ) {}

          newMemberForm!: FormGroup;
          newUploadFile(event: any) {
            const file: File = event.target.files ? event.target.files[0] : null;
            if (file) {
              this.file_arr = file;
              this.isImageChanged = true;
            }
          }
            onSave() {
                        const id = this._activeRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
                          const formData = new FormData();
                          formData.append('fname'this.newMemberForm.get('fname')?.value);
            
                          formData.append('lname',this.newMemberForm.get('lname')?.value);
                           if (this.isImageChanged) {
                    formData.append('image', this.file_arr);
                  } else if (this.currentImageUrl) {
                    formData.append('image', this.currentImageUrl);
                  }
                  const headers = new HttpHeaders();
                    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
                    headers.append('accept', 'application/json');
                    headers.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
                    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    console.log(formData)
                 
                  this._memberService.editMember(id, formData,headers).subscribe({
                    next: (res: any) => {
                      alert('Updated');
                      console.log('from server ',res);
                      //console.log(this.newMemberForm.value);
                    },
                                error: (err: any) => {
                      console.error(err);
                      alert('Error updating employee.');
                    },
                  });
                }
```

Service code is

```
         editMember(id: number, data: any,headers:any) {
            // return this._http.put(${this.employeeUrl}/${id}, data);
            return this._http.put(`${this.memberApi}/${id}`, data,{headers});

          }
```

Laravel route

```
            Route::resource('new-member', 'Api\MemberCtrl');
```

Controller

```
        public function update(Request $request, $id)
            {
                if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
                    $photo = $request->file('image');
                    $photo_name = '';
                      if($photo)
                      {
                          $photo_name = rand() . '.' . $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
                          $photo->move(public_path('images'), $photo_name);
                          $photo_name = url('public/images/'.$photo_name);
                      }
                    $data =  array(
                        'fname'=>$request->fname,
                        'lname'=>$request->lname,
                        'image'=>$photo_name
                     );
                }else{
                    $data =  array(
                        'fname'=>$request->fname,
                        'lname'=>$request->lname
                     );
                }
                
                
                $update = DB::table($this->tbl)->where('id',$id)->update($data);
                if($update){
                    return response()->json(['message'=>'Successfully updated.']);
                }else{
                    return response()->json(['error'=>true,'message'=>'Error while saving data']);
                }
            }
```

I am expecting to get all request to laravel end server keeping angular _http.put request. I don't want to use use  _http.post, in place of _http.put in angular. If we change _http.post, laravel end server is able to receive all the request. But I want just keep as _http.put.Please help.